# Can I try several CFAs on the same data before choosing one for generating factor scores?

Tags: factor-analysis, latent-variable, confirmatory-factor, matching

I'm interested in matching on latent constructs (see Raykov, 2012), and one way to do so is to match on factor scores generated by CFAs of the items (One could also match on the items themselves, but this yields bias in outcome estimation due to measurement error). The issue is that I'm not sure of the factor structure of my items.

My items are academic variables like standardized test scores, AP scores, etc. I'm interested on matching on, for example "math ability", which is measured by several items in my variable list. But I'm not sure what the correct correlation structure is among my variables; obviously the math-related items load on the same factor, but it's also the case that non-math related items are correlated with math related items (due to coming from the same test session or because general factors influence both math and non-math items).

Am I "allowed" to run several CFAs on my data to see which model yields the best fit, then generate my factor scores from that model to be then used in my matching analysis? Or is doing so unduly capitalizing on chance, yielding biased results?

Comment: I would recommend that if you have clearly articulated theories of measurement in advance, then you would be fine testing these particular measurement models using CFA. But if you're totally in the dark about what your measurement structure is likely the be, you might consider using EFA, as opposed to CFA, as this is precisely the sort of problem that EFA methods are intended to help you solve (and you can still get factor scores from EFA solutions; just make sure to evaluate their determinacy)